# Graphic Card seems to be put to sleep when no screen is attached

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I recently installed some new computers with the following configuration :
- Graphic Card : NVidia GeForce GTX 1060 3G
- OS : Windows 10

These computers are used as servers and have no screen attached (I access them via VNC).

The issue is that when no screen is attached, Windows seems to put the graphic card to sleep. As a results, I can't access all the options of the NVidia Control Panel, VNC becomes painfully slow, and my other GPU applications have troubles (as if they used the processor graphic chipset).

However, if I plug a screen to the computer, everything becomes normal again (all the options are present in the NVidia Control Panel and VNC works fine). The devices manager doesn't display any difference between the 2 states (screen plugged/unplugged)

Searching a bit on Google, I found [this](https://rumorscity.com/2013/12/06/how-to-create-dummy-plugs-for-your-graphics-cards/) that seems to provide an hardware solution to a similar issue of mine. It also led me on the ULPS (Ultra Low Power State) that also seems to be a nice way to handle that, but limited to AMD cards (It seems to use a register key that is absent on my machine).

Is there any software way to get my card "active" all the time, even when no screen is connected?

Thank you,

Comment: I have solved similar problems in the past by going into Device Manager, finding the card, then looking for a "Power" tab where there sometimes is an option for how the card should decide when to power down.  This is especially important for WLAN cards that drop connections when the computer is asleep, but might have some bearing on your video card.